# How to undraw multiple polygons with zelle graphics

Tags: python, polygon, undo

The assignment was to create a program that allows you to connect points and then draw them. 
Now I have to create an undraw and to do so I have to remember/store the polygons being created by creating a new list. I am not sure how to create the new list and the use undraw() to undo this

```
pointList = []
polyList = []
pList = []

pt = win.getMouse()
while not isClicked(exitBtn, pt):
    if isClicked(drawBtn, pt):
        poly = Polygon(pointList)  
        r, g, b = eval(colorEntry.getText())
        poly.setFill(color_rgb(r,g,b))
        poly.draw(win)
        pointList = []

    else:
        pointList.append(pt)
        pt.draw(win)
    pt = win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

main()